# How do I heappush lists from a matrix by a certain index while preserving the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, binary-heap

Say I have a list:

`l1 = [[1, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1]]`

I want to push each item in `l1` to a binary heap, 'memory' but sorted in the binary heap by `each_item[-1]`.

I've tried: `heapq.heappush(_heap, item=itemgetter(-1))` and the equivilent using an anonymous function but I get:

`TypeError: heappush() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: You should just reverse the inputs as they go into the heap.  They will naturally be sorted by their first values (the last values of the initial list).

Comment: @fferri Great, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to make small wrappers around `heapq` functions to prepend/extract the sorting value to/from the item in a consistent way:

```
def heappush(h, item, key=lambda x: x):
    heapq.heappush(h, (key(item), item))

def heappop(h):
    return heapq.heappop(h)[1]

def heapify(h, key=lambda x: x):
    for idx, item in enumerate(h):
        h[idx] = (key(item), item)
    heapq.heapify(h)
```

Testing with your sample:

```
l1 = [[1, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1]]
h = []
for item in l1:
    heappush(h, item, key=itemgetter(-1))

while h:
    print(heappop(h))
```

Prints:

```
[2, 1]
[3, 2]
[1, 3]
```

Note that you could use `h=l1; heapify(h, key=itemgetter(-1))` which should be faster than individually `heappush`ing each item.

Answer (score 3):

You can store entries in the heap as 3-element tuples including the last element, an entry count, and the actual item. This way the items will be sorted by their last values with the entry count ensuring sort stability (i.e. two items with equal last elements are returned in the order they were added):

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heap = []
>>> l1 = [[1, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1]]
>>> for count, item in enumerate(l1):
...     heapq.heappush(heap, (item[-1], count, item))
... 
>>> while heap:
...     print(heapq.heappop(heap)[-1])
... 
[2, 1]
[3, 2]
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Eugene's solution but if working with this special tuple a lot, one could define a custom object to achieve this as follows:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class MyTupleHeapObj(object):
    def __init__(self,val): self.val = val
    def __lt__(self,other): return self.val[-1] < other.val[-1]
    def __eq__(self,other): return self.val == other.val
    def __str__(self): return str(self.val)

h = []
for item in [[1, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1]]:
    heappush(h, MyTupleHeapObj(item))

while h:
    print heappop(h)
```

---

Prints the following:

```
[2, 1]
[3, 2]
[1, 3]
```